# Line Chart Hide-Show With Buttons But Keep Colors

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I get data from a table and create a line chart.
I use buttons to toggle the lines.

```
<div id="checkboxes" style="min-height: 100px;">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom1" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom1"><span class="check_icon"></span>TSH</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom2" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom2"><span class="check_icon"></span>FT3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom3" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom3"><span class="check_icon"></span> FT4</label>
</div>
<div name="curve_chart" id="curve_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; "></div>

<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY `vdate` ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->query();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    $chartentry .= "['".date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['vdate']))."', ".$row{'check_tsh'}.", ".$row{'check_ft3'}.", ".$row{'check_ft4'}."],";
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['vdate', 'THS', 'FT3', 'FT4'],
    <?php echo $chartentry ?>
]);

var options = {
    legendTextStyle: {color: '#757575'},
    fontName: 'Didact Gothic',
    curveType: 'function',
    height: 300,
    pointSize: 5,
    series: {0: { color: '#000000' },1: { color: '#D20000' },2: { color: '#5CB85C' },},
    hAxis: {title: 'Visit', titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'Didact Gothic', color: '#757575'}, textStyle:{color: '#757575'}},
    vAxis: {title: 'Prices', titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'Didact Gothic', color: '#757575'}, textStyle:{color: '#757575'}, viewWindow: {min:0}}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
                        2,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
                        3,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation"}]);
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(view, options);
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // do stuff on "ready" event
    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
    view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
var tes =[0];

    if($("#kolom1").is(':checked')) {tes.push(1,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"});}
    if($("#kolom2").is(':checked')) {tes.push(2,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"});}
    if($("#kolom3").is(':checked')) {tes.push(3,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation"});}
    view.setColumns(tes);       
    chart.draw(view, options);
    });
});
</script>
```

All works but when the chart is updated after hidding or showing a line the line colors change and this can be really confusing if you have a lot of lines.
Is there away to set colors to the lines that will not change even if 1 or more of them are hidden?

Comment: side note: looks like the ending curly brace for `drawChart` is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the `series` option to define line colors,
use the `colors` option with a simple array

then when the lines change, add the applicable colors from the original array

also, you can rely on the google callback to know when the document is ready

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['vdate', 'THS', 'FT3', 'FT4'],
      [new Date('08/01/2016'), 10, 20, 30],
      [new Date('08/02/2016'), 20, 40, 60]
    ]);

    var chartColors = ['#000000', '#D20000', '#5CB85C'];

    var options = {
      legendTextStyle: {color: '#757575'},
      fontName: 'Didact Gothic',
      curveType: 'function',
      height: 300,
      pointSize: 5,
      colors: chartColors,
      hAxis: {title: 'Visit', titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'Didact Gothic', color: '#757575'}, textStyle:{color: '#757575'}},
      vAxis: {title: 'Prices', titleTextStyle: {fontName: 'Didact Gothic', color: '#757575'}, textStyle:{color: '#757575'}, viewWindow: {min:0}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
                        2,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"},
                        3,{ calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation"}]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(view, options);

    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
      view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      var tes =[0];
      var selectedColors = [];

      if($("#kolom1").is(':checked')) {
        tes.push(1,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation"});
        selectedColors.push(chartColors[0]);
      }
      if($("#kolom2").is(':checked')) {
        tes.push(2,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation"});
        selectedColors.push(chartColors[1]);
      }
      if($("#kolom3").is(':checked')) {
        tes.push(3,{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation"});
        selectedColors.push(chartColors[2]);
      }
      view.setColumns(tes);
      options.colors = selectedColors;
      chart.draw(view, options);
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes" style="min-height: 100px;">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom1" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom1"><span class="check_icon"></span>TSH</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom2" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom2"><span class="check_icon"></span>FT3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" style="display: none;" id="kolom3" checked="checked" /><label class="medexams" for="kolom3"><span class="check_icon"></span> FT4</label>
</div>
<div name="curve_chart" id="curve_chart" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; "></div>
```